# C# to read file into Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file which I am required to parse, validate and then load into a SQL Server database using Interop. I have the application working and everything is fine by reading a sheet, reading each line (row and columns) and adding that line to an List as an Insert statement. When I reach the end of the Worksheet, I execute all of the Insert statements as one batch.

The problem I have is that it is using a lot of RAM when the worksheet is big (1000+ rows). Is there a better or more efficient strategy for larger data? Should I be committing more and clearing the List?

Comment: Don't know if you save that much on memory, but a "better or more efficient strategy for larger data" would probably be using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: for other suggestions it would be better if we could see your code. Possibly there are some other lines to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do on the parsing side (unless you are coding it all yourself), but I'd `INSERT` the data as soon as you have a row available. No need to store it in a list. In your solution, you are basically storing all data twice (once in the "Excel memory" and once in "database insert memory").